# Display Only Month From Mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code displays date as: 13-07-2016
I want to display only month and year. Example: "July 2016"
How do I modify this code so that it gets Only month and year and displays it.
Code:

```
   <td><?=$this->wll->getDateFormate(6,$row['bill_date'])?></td>
```

Comment: We don't know what is `wll` and what does `getDateFomate` do.

Comment: If only PHP had some [date functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)...

Comment: If only MYSQL had some [date funtions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = $row['bill_date'];
$month = date('F', strtotime($date));
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));

<td><?php echo $month . ' ' . $year; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a switch on your display text. Something like this:

```
var month_number = display_text[3] + display_text[3];
var month;
switch (month_number)
    case "01":
        month = "Jan";
        break;
...
```

And display thath month with the other characters, like:

```
show: display_text[0] + display_text[1] + "-" + month + ...
```

Comment: I don't know much coding, can you modify the code, pls?

Comment: Sory firend, I'm not keen on php. Try searching [String handling](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.strings.php) and [switch structures](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime():`

```
$time=strtotime($dateValue);
$month=date("F",$time);
$year=date("Y",$time);
```

Or you can do something like...

```
$dateElements = explode('-', $dateValue);
$year = $dateElements[0];

echo $year;    //2012

switch ($dateElements[1]) {

   case '01'    :  $mo = "January";
                   break;

   case '02'    :  $mo = "February";
                   break;

   case '03'    :  $mo = "March";
                   break;

     .
     .
     .

   case '12'    :  $mo = "December";
                   break;


}

echo $mo;      //January
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case amend your query to provide that data you want to use rather than trying to manipulate it post query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(theDateCol, '%M %Y') as theMonthAndYear, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_format($row['bill_date], "F Y");
```

F -> Full Month Letters and  Y -> 4 digit Year

Comment: Would you like to explain that just a little bit. Otherwise it looks like a comment and that will probably get downvotes